# Programmatically position control in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am creating a karaoke program in WPF. Basically, I have a MediaElement which plays vidioes and such, and a StackPanel atop of that which I use to render stuff on top of the MediaElement.

I am trying to programmatically add a TextBlock to the StackPanel, which is going display the lyrics. The problem is that the TextBlock ends up in the top left corner no matter what I write.

```
Private LyricLabel As New TextBlock 

Sub New(Panel As StackPanel)
    With LyricLabel
        .Foreground = Brushes.White
        .FontFamily = New FontFamily("Verdana")
        .FontSize = 20

        .HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
        .VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom
    End With

    Panel.Children.Add(LyricLabel)
End Sub
```

Also, I want a ball or something to jump from word to word. Is there a easy way to get the width of each of the words + the space between them, or do I have to calculate that by myself?

Comment: You will want to use the `Margin` property: `.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, right,bottom);`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 The margin property does place the TextBlock where I want it, but it does not re-arrange itself when the Panel is resized. There surely must be a way to specify an anchor?

Comment: The "anchor" is determined by the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Please forgive me for being a complete idiot, I'm totally new to WPF you see; the HorizontalAlignment property works perfectly, and I can place the text wherever I desire. The VerticalAlignment property however, does not. No mater what I specify the text ends up at the of my panel.

Comment: Don't use a stack panel, then, but a grid.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error Thanks, you should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a better option to use a `Grid` and do that entirely in XAML. The `Grid` has the property that if many elements are in the same cell, they all overlap. So you put the MediaElement and a TextBlock together, with proper alignments and you're done:

```
<Grid>
    <MediaElement/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentLyric}" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0 0 0 30"/>
</Grid>
```

You just have to provide a property for dropping the current text to be shown for the binding to work, and it will adjust it for you.